# Padding different in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

In all the browsers I've tested, my button looks like this:

[image]

Except in Firefox where it looks like this:

[image]

[I've posted the code as a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuxXw/1/), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using a CSS reset, Firefox adds in a lot of extra padding, borders, etc... http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @tdun I'm using `normalize.css`, I thought I'd captured all the styles that apply...

Comment: I think it's normal for me in FF 15: http://prntscr.com/fydeg

Comment: @TomMedley I think Brian's answer is correct, using line-height and removing padding will be more consistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a normal site, you should always include a reset to get rid of these small inconsistencies between browsers. Here's a simple one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

*(Edit: Ok, you use normalize, that could also work)*

However, in your case I would also suggest instead of using padding on the top and bottom, remove them and your height and instead use line-height! This will keep your text nicely centered everywhere.